# Regular Expression to match no tags except <br>

Tags: regex

We need to match text from a user input, but specifically reject any tags that aren't `<br>`.

From other stackoverflow posts I can find the opposite match to what I need (i.e. it matches the offending tags rather than the text and the other tag).  Due to constraints we can't use negative logic to this for validation.  The regex is:

```
<(?!\/?br(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>
```

Is it possible to match the whole text if it only contains "normal" text and BR tags?

For example these should match:

```
bob
bob<br>bob
bob<br />bob
bob</br>
```

These should fail to match

```
bob<p>bob
bob<div>bob
bob</div>bob
```

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/dK5dX1/1 ? This `<(?=\/?br(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>` would do the opposite of regex you mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Java for some reason (sorry should have said) - checking here: - http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @AshMcConnell Better to always specify the regex flavor/language, if specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use two negative [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?si)^(?!.*<(?!\/?br\b)\w).*
```

as a Java string:

```
"(?si)^(?!.*<(?!\\/?br\\b)\\w).*"
```

Used `s` (dot match newline too), `i` (caseless) [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

[test at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/pucbm) (click on Java); [test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bP0qA3/2); see [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great!

Comment: @AshMcConnell Glad, could have been of help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|[^<>]*<\s*(\/)?\s*br\s*(\/)?\s*>[^<>]*)^.*$
```

You can try this.This use postive lookahead.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kO7lO2/4

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would work,

```
String s = "bob\n" + 
        "bob<br>bob\n" + 
        "bob<br />bob\n" + 
        "bob</br>\n" +
        "bob<p>bob\n" + 
        "bob<div>bob\n" + 
        "bob</div>bob";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\w+(?:<(?=\\/?br(?=>|\\s.*>))\\/?.*?>(?:\\w+)?)?$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
       System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Output:

```
bob
bob<br>bob
bob<br />bob
bob</br
```